# JPA + Hibernate : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I wanted to use batch insertion / update provided by hibernate(using MySQL 5.7) as given in [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update).
I got to know that we cannot used batch inserts / updates for entities having id generation as IDENTITY.
More info: [Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if you use an IDENTITY identifier generator.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html)

So, I changed `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` for one of the hibernate entity and started getting the below error.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.addToBatch(BatchingBatch.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3026) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3547) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1002' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:191) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:166) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:173) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:224) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(ClientPreparedStatement.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:447) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:814) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:2544) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.addToBatch(BatchingBatch.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3026) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3547) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 7 more
```

These are the hibernate settings I am using for config.

```
extraProperties.put(Environment.ORDER_UPDATES, true);
extraProperties.put(Environment.ORDER_INSERTS, true);
extraProperties.put(Environment.BATCH_VERSIONED_DATA, true);
extraProperties.put(Environment.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, false);
extraProperties.put(Environment.USE_GET_GENERATED_KEYS, false);
extraProperties.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
extraProperties.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
extraProperties.put(Environment.STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, 100);
```

Seems like the id is already present in DB.
Do I need to make any more change for change the `GenerationType`?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @OleksiiMLD I am using MySQL 5.7, have added more details

Answer (score 0):

To use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` database engine must support sequences.

A sequence is a separate database object. (more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-sequences/)

MySql doesn't support sequences. So you can't use annotation in such form. Also read about `@SequenceGenerator`: https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys.

But you can try some Hibernate trick with `SequenceStyleGenerator` described here https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers.